# Edits to a Multicam Clip in Final Cut Pro do not Show Up in Timeline

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, fcpx

I have a Multicam clip with about 8 different angles in Final Cut Pro 10.4.8, and have them automatically synced and made some manual adjustments to get all the clips to line up properly.  This worked well, and so I dragged this Multicam clip into my timeline and started making cuts.  I made several cuts among the camera angles and they all take effect as I would expect.  The Multicam clip is the only clip in my Project Timeline.

Today, I'm reviewing the Multicam clip and noticing that one angle is slightly off.  I double clicked the Multicam clip to open the editor and made the adjustment to the offending angle.  When I view it in the Multicam clip editor, everything lines up perfectly.  However, when I go back to my timeline, my edit does not take effect.  The angle is off as it was originally.  If I open a new project and drag that Multicam clip into a new project, I see the same results.  Every time I double click the Multicam clip to edit it, my fix is there and the angle is synced correctly.

Any ideas why the clips are synced in the Multicam clip editor, but in the timeline, they appear out of sync?  Many thanks in advance for help with this perplexing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick idea I would try to delete the Optimized, Proxy and/or rendered media, let FCPX create all new and see if that makes a difference.

[Manage render files in Final Cut Pro](https://support.apple.com/guide/final-cut-pro/manage-render-files-ver68a8c250/mac)